# Listen for a save file dialog window in an application, then automate saving it?

Tags: c#

Sorry if this is a vague question, it's a very specific case and difficult to explain. Here's what I'm trying to do (this is for a 64 bit Windows application by the way)

1. Look to see if a particular save file dialog window is open inside an application (image of it below, it's a dialog box that pops up inside of the application when exporting something)
2. Once I have a pointer to that window, somehow access and use its elements in such a way that I'm able to name the file I'm saving, navigate to a desired file path, then save it, all through code

Here's a photo of the window that I'm trying to control through code (for reference)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBKOQ.png)

So far I've been able to find code that gives me all the active windows, including the one I'm targeting. Here is that code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;



using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using HWND = System.IntPtr;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>Contains functionality to get all the open windows.</summary>
public static class OpenWindowGetter
{
    /// <summary>Returns a dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</summary>
    /// <returns>A dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</returns>
    public static IDictionary<HWND, string> GetOpenWindows()
    {
        HWND shellWindow = GetShellWindow();
        Dictionary<HWND, string> windows = new Dictionary<HWND, string>();

        EnumWindows(delegate (HWND hWnd, int lParam)
        {
            if (hWnd == shellWindow) return true;
            if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

            int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            if (length == 0) return true;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, length + 1);

            windows[hWnd] = builder.ToString();
            return true;

        }, 0);

        return windows;
    }

    private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, int lParam);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(HWND hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(HWND hWnd);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(HWND hWnd);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
}


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> window in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
            {
                IntPtr handle = window.Key;
                string title = window.Value;

                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", handle, title);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what to do from here. What I need now help with now is checking for the particular window I'm targeting (named Export Selection as seen in the photo).. then somehow get references to its components and control them.

I've looked into using Spy++ to get info about the components, and then using FindWindowEx and SendMessage to control them. This is not something I completely understand, as I'm limited in my C# knowledge. Is this the correct approach, and if so how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It's a bit complicated, but basically I'm automating a mass export of objects from this software, and unfortunately the software is designed to open a dialog box like this for every object, and there's no way to change that. This will be for thousands of files, so it's not practical to manually use a dialog box for each one. Ideally I'd like this program to detect whenever a dialog box appears, and save it. To clarify further, this is game dev software with a built in level/model editor, and I'm exporting all the items in the level as obj files for editing in Blender.

Comment: Is it going to be a predictable set of actions, such as you start a script that invoked Save and then within 3 seconds the dialog will have appeared etc. Or is it unpredictable (user will ctrl-s randomly and you want to react to the window but there is no script to it)

Comment: (Personally I would probably just automate it with autohotkey, to do a repetitive set of keystrokes on a timer, perhaps incrementing a number by 1 each time to give a different filename, but it might not be possible if you don't have predictability in timing)

Comment: It will be predictable, yes. I'm running a script inside this game dev program that automates the exporting of models. It essentially loops through all the items in the level, and exports them one by one with a delay of approx 1/30th of a second. A dialog window pops up for each one.. so I have hundreds of dialog boxes appearing in seconds basically. I could slow this down if needed, I control the delay.

Comment: So you could select 300 objects, run your script, 300 save dialogs appear over the course of 10 seconds and then you could start a c# app that just uses sendkeys 300 times to type 300 filenames pressing return in each one. No need for even inspecting windows, you're just faced with Window #2 after you dismissed window #1 etc?

Comment: That's correct. One issue I have been facing is when too many dialog boxes appear it crashes the application. I suppose I could do it in increments of say 100 at a time, that should work. This is definitely something worth trying, I think it'll work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, using Spy++ is a good approach to understand that application and its controls. As you seem already to be able to detect the correct window, the next step is now to use the `SendMessage` function to send data to the individual controls of the window. Look up in the Win32 API documentation to find the correct messages to send. I.e. you would use the WM_SETTEXT message to put text into the "File name" input box. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settext.

Or you use the [SetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtexta) function, which basically does the same, but is easier to use. You already have the prototype for the `GetWindowText` method declared in your code. The C# declaration for `SetWindowText` should be

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
private static extern int SetWindowText(HWND hWnd, String lpString);
```